# io.debezium.DebeziumException: Client requested master to start replication from impossible position

Tags: mysql, mariadb, binlog, mariadb-10.5, kafka

I am using Kafka and Debezium to connect to a MariaDB

I have a problem where in the event the MariaDB loses power and shutsdown abruptly, on restart Debezium is no longer able to connect

I have this error in particular

```
[2023-12-06 13:26:05,800] ERROR [192.168.108.1|task-0] Error during binlog processing. Last offset stored = null, binlog reader near position = mariadb-bin.000006/53938 (io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource:1161)
```

```
io.debezium.DebeziumException: Client requested master to start replication from impossible position; the first event 'mariadb-bin.000006' at 53938, the last event read from 'mariadb-bin.000006' at 4, the last byte read from 'mariadb-bin.000006' at 4. Error code: 1236; SQLSTATE: HY000.
```

And on the mariadb side i have this

```
+--------------------+-----------+
| Log_name           | File_size |
+--------------------+-----------+
| mariadb-bin.000001 |       330 |
| mariadb-bin.000002 |       330 |
| mariadb-bin.000003 |     67494 |
| mariadb-bin.000004 |     69007 |
| mariadb-bin.000005 |    126922 |
| mariadb-bin.000006 |     45056 |
| mariadb-bin.000007 |    103304 |
+--------------------+-----------+
7 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> show master status;
+--------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| File               | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+--------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| mariadb-bin.000007 |   103304 |              |                  |
+--------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

I have tried resetting offsets on Kafka side of things but I get the exact same error without fail, does anyone know why exactly there is a problem and how to resolve things? All help appreciated thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Change configuration to include `sync_binlog = 1` on the Primary and restart the server.

and move the pointer (on the Replica) to the beginning (Pos=0 or 4) of the next binlog (on the Primary).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46366177/1766831

Comment: Hey thanks for help, I added this to config file on the mariadb side but I still get the same error :( You have any idea how to change the bin log stuff in Kafka by any chance? I spent entire day trying to change it but very consistently it's trying to read from the same binlog file and position

Comment: I added a few more details.